# How can I address my emulator to my localhost with my IP address?

Tags: windows-10, android, localhost, emulator

I am trying [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/), but it seems I must address the emulator to the localhost with something like this: `http://192.168.1.5:3000`. But this doesn't work and also when I test it in my browser doesn't work too. But I can reach `http://localhost:3000` from my browser!

What is the problem?
I checked my IPv4 address and that's true!

The suggestion to use an IP address came from a [comment to a question I asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577315/error-referenceerror-errorevent-is-not-defined-for-nativescript-app/56613103?noredirect=1#comment99806587_56613103). Details of the the full problem are given there.

EDIT: I changed related line of code in my program as bellow:

`export const baseURL = "https://10.0.2.2:3000/";`

But the problem still exist and I get the same error with the new URL address as well.

Comment: Based on the comments, are you certain your json server is set to respond correctly? Might it only be set to respond to `localhost` or perhaps `127.0.0.1`? If it's set to respond to either of those and not the virtual IP address of the emulator (or rather, http requests from other devices broadly), that could be an issue.

Comment: @Anaksunaman: Thanks for remark. I don't know really. I am a new learner. How can I check that?

Comment: Well, offhand, I might suggest to have look at [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/pricing) if you generally just need  to do some web API testing. That said, I am not certain it would do much if what I suggest is the case. You would need to look at the configuration for the server itself or perhaps the actual commands used to start it (if it's some sort of scripting language server, for instance). Perhaps you might wish to include some details about what is actually responding to your app (the json server).

Comment: Every IPv4 connwcted system has an address 127.9.0.1 = localhost - This is typically a different interface to the ethernet Interface. My guess is the program us listening only on that interface.

Comment: @davidgo: Neither 127.0.0.1 nor 127.9.0.1 didn't work

Comment: did you try 127.0.0.1:3000 ? If so, what IP responds when you "ping localhost"

Comment: @davidgo: yep, didn't work!